# Unable to start Chrome browser with user profile in Selenium

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to open a Chrome browser window with an existing user profile.

```
    String dir= "/Users/labuser/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome";        
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--user-data-dir="+dir);
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options); // throws an exception!
```

I confirmed the `user directory path` by looking at `chrome://version` page. (screenshot below)

[image]

Due to some reason, this code throws an exception with very less information

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506106 (8a06c39c4582fbfbab6966dbb1c38a9173bfb1a2),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.33 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:00:58'
System info: host: 'arustagi-wx-3', ip: '10.41.25.35', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.6', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:148)
```

**Edit**

I am using the following chrome browser, this falls in the supported range of browsers

```
Version 61.0.3163.100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got this fixed. I was working on macOS and found out that i needed to quit the browser cleanly.

After closing the browser window, i had to right click on the icon in the dock and press quit. The selenium script would work perfectly fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the latest version of the ChromeDriver

```
chromedriver=2.33.506106
```

with Selenium **2.53**. You should use the [latest release](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/releases).

Anyway, what is your browser version? [Here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33/notes.txt) you can take a look which are the browsers version supported (based on your chromedriver).

**EDIT**

I tried with:

- Selenium 3.5.3
- ChromeDriver v2.33
- Google Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

From **`chrome://version/`**, my profile path is

```
/Volumes/MacintoshSSD/Users/DurdenP/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

Trying

```
    String chromeDriver ="pathTo/ChromeDriver/chromedriver";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    String dir= "/Volumes/MacintoshSSD/Users/DurdenP/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome";
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir="+dir);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

it works.

Comment: I tried the same with version 3.6.0 instead of 2.53. Got the same exception.

Comment: I checked my browser version - 61.0.3163.100, it falls in the supported range

Comment: @AnkitRustagi I've just edited the answer. I hope could help you.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! It turned out to be a silly issue.